# A function with compact support

Tags: distribution-theory

Suppose that $\phi$ is a test function on $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\phi$ has compact support, there exists $R>0$ such that $\operatorname{supp} \phi\subseteq [-R,R]$.

The way I understand from this is that $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x\notin [-R,R]$. But what about the endpoints, i.e. $\phi(\pm R)?$

Comment: These functions are traditionally taken to be continuous, so they would necessarily be $0$ at the endpoints.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Right, isn't a test function already a smooth function by definition? What I am trying to understand is why $\phi$ is zero at the endpoints

Comment: @CameronWilliams If we take a sequence $(R_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus [-R,R]$ with the property that $R_n\to R$ as $n\to \infty$. Then $\phi(R_n)\to \phi(R)$ by continuity. Since $\phi(R_n)=0$, and by uniqueness of limits, one must get $\phi(R)=0$ as well. Another endpoint is similar. Is that why?

Comment: Test function means $C^\infty(\Bbb{R})$ and zero outside $[-R,R]$ for some $R$. Example: $e^{-1/(1-x^2)}1_{|x|<1}$. Non-examples: $e^x, e^x 1_{|x|<1}$. From there we can prove that its support, the closure of the set where $\phi$ is non-zero is an union of finitely many closed intervals.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for your comments. Is there a way to prove it formally? I made one above; could this work?

Comment: Proving what ? ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\phi$ is unequal to $0$ at the endpoints of the interval. W/o loss of generality, we pick $R$ for investigation. Since $\phi$ is a test function it is smooth, therefore it is also continuous. Hence, there exists a small neighborhood around $R$ where $\phi>0$ holds. This, however, contradicts that $supp(\phi)$ is a subset of the interval $[-R,R]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\phi$ is continuous we have $\lim_{x\to R} \phi(x) = \phi(R)$ and since $\lim_{x\to R} \phi(x)$ exists we have $\lim_{x\to R} \phi(x) = \lim_{x\to R+} \phi(x).$ Thus,
$$
\phi(R) = \lim_{x\to R} \phi(x) = \lim_{x\to R+} \phi(x) = \lim_{x\to R+} 0 = 0.
$$

Likewise, we get for $\phi(-R) = 0.$